# Lock FlexDashboard Markdown for edits

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to find a way to make a FlexDashboard (using Shiny runtime) accessible to a colleague without access to the internet.

To provide my colleague with the full interactive experience (drop-down menus etc), I was thinking of simply installing R on my colleagues laptop and share the markdown script with them but does anyone know a way to lock the script for edits?

I just want to make sure that there is no accidental edits which might mess up the running of the markdown.

Look forward to hearing any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a shiny application tweak it perfectly and then write a docker script to run they shiny application as an independent entity,

Your friend can use that docker container to run the dashboard and interact with it, but has no need of opening the script or anything else, just bake all the functionality into the shiny application and call the docker container and the flexdashboard will publish to a console.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am relatively new to R so a docker script is not something I have come across before but I will definitely look into it!

Comment: try this: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/ and this: https://juanitorduz.github.io/dockerize-a-shinyapp/ in that order!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing, sconfluentus!